# How alignement horizontaly with constraints?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How can i alignement horizontaly  three elements [A B C] one before of other with constraints?

```
public static void AddConstraintsElements(UIView View, UIView element, UIView element2, UIView element3)
        {
            NSLayoutConstraint.ActivateConstraints(new[] {
                element.TopAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, constant: 20),
                element.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(View.LeadingAnchor, constant: 100),
                element.WidthAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(View.WidthAnchor, 1),
                element.HeightAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(View.HeightAnchor, 1),

                element2.BottomAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, constant: 20),
                element2.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(View.LeadingAnchor, constant: 120),
                element2.WidthAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo( 1),
                element2.HeightAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo( 1),

                element3.BottomAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, constant: 20),
                element3.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo(View.LeadingAnchor, constant: 120),
                element3.WidthAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo( 1),
                element3.HeightAnchor.ConstraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo( 1)
            });
        }
```

[image]

other case with first and second element, the third element remove please
:

[image]

i tried but it's not working

```
element1.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(25).Active = true;
            element1.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(element1.WidthAnchor).Active = true;

            element2.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(30).Active = true;
            element2.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(30).Active = true;



            element1.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(element2.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;

            element1.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 15).Active = true;
            element2.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 15).Active = true;

            element1.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo( View.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
            element2.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.RightAnchor).Active = true;
```

Comment: Do you want them to fill the view horizontally, with some margin between them or what should it look like? It is unclear from your question what effect you want.

Comment: @Cheesebaron without nothing of margin between them

Comment: Still unclear, maybe make a quick drawing of what you want to achieve.

Comment: _still_ unclear whether leading edge of A and trailing edge of C are touching the edges of the screen. How do you determine the height?

Comment: So you want them centered on the screen too?

Comment: @Cheesebaron a help more please, how ca i the third element traslate at the end the row?

Comment: traslate? I don't understand

Comment: @Cheesebaron i edited my question, see please

Comment: Just set TrailingAnchor to View.TrailingAnchor with a margin?

Comment: @Cheesebaron i tried but i do not work, help me please please!!!

Comment: I think it warrants a new question with a description and some description of what you have tried.

Comment: i can not do more question, i am blocked

Comment: @Cheesebaron i need your help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187327/how-alignement-two-elements-with-contraints please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to align them something like:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                       ^                       |
|                      120                      |
|                       v                       |
|       +---------++---------++---------+       |
|       |         ||         ||         |       |
|       |    A    ||    B    ||    C    |       |
|       |         ||         ||         |       |
|       +---------++---------++---------+       |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
```

Where the items are centered and 120 points from the top and they have a fixed width and height. You could do something like:

```cs
// set widths and heights
a.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(25).Active = true;
a.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(a.WidthAnchor).Active = true;

b.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(25).Active = true;
b.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(b.WidthAnchor).Active = true;

c.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(25).Active = true;
c.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(c.WidthAnchor).Active = true;

// align B view as the middle view
b.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;

// align A to left of B
a.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(b.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;

// align C to right of B
c.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(b.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;

// align A, B and C, 120 points from the top
a.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 120).Active = true;
b.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 120).Active = true;
c.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 120).Active = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would center justify B, and set the width as height as preferred then match A and C to the width, height, and vertical of B, and the space A and C horizontally in reference to B as preferred.

So

B -> Width, Height, Vertical, Horizontal

A -> Match Width with B, match Height with B, match Vertical with B, set Horizontal in reference to B's location (like -15 or something)

C -> Match Width with B, match Height with B, match vertical with B, set Horizontal in reference to B's location (like +15 or something)