# How alignement two elements with contraints?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

i want alignement two elements, one in the center and the other in right side

```
a.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(25).Active = true;
            a.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(element1.WidthAnchor).Active = true;

            b.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(30).Active = true;
            b.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(30).Active = true;



            a.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(element2.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;

            a.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 15).Active = true;
            b.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 15).Active = true;

            a.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo( View.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
            b.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.RightAnchor).Active = true;
```

i tried but this is not work

i want same than this picture:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+(screen)
|                       ^                               |
|                      120                              |
|                       v                               |
|                    +---------+          +---------+   |
|                    |         |          |         |   |
|                    |    A    |          |    C    |<10> 
|                    |         |          |         |   |
|                    +---------+          +---------+   |
|                                                       |
|                                                       |
|                                                       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public UILabel labelOne { get; private set; }
    public UILabel labelTwo { get; private set; }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        labelOne = new UILabel();
        labelTwo = new UILabel();

        labelOne.Text = "test1";
        labelTwo.Text = "test2";
        labelOne.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        labelTwo.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        labelOne.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        labelTwo.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

        labelOne.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        labelTwo.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        View.Add(labelOne);
        View.Add(labelTwo);


        updateC();
    }

    public void updateC() {

        View.AddConstraints(new[] {
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(labelOne, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 80),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(labelOne, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 80),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(labelOne, NSLayoutAttribute.Top , NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 120),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(labelOne, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0)
        });

        View.AddConstraints(new[] {
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(labelTwo, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 80),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(labelTwo, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 80),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(labelTwo, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, labelOne, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(labelTwo, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, -10)
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Update:

```
public void updateC() {

    labelOne.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(30).Active = true;
    labelOne.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(30).Active = true;

    labelTwo.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(30).Active = true;
    labelTwo.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(30).Active = true;

    labelOne.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 120).Active = true;
    labelTwo.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(labelOne.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;

    labelOne.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
    labelTwo.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.RightAnchor, -10).Active = true;

}
```

Comment: your answer is good, but i need with this sintaxis .Active = true; as well, can you adding in your answer please

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278518/how-center-many-buttons-with-constraints please!!!

Answer (score 0):

we have 3 views here: container view, bigger view, smaller view.
1. set bigger view's centerX,Y constraints equal to container view's centerX,Y constraints.
2. set smaller view's centerY constraint equal to container view's centerY.
3. set smaller view's right anchor equal to container view's right anchor with offset -8 (or whatever you want)
Hope it helps.

Comment: the views are the same size

Comment: i dont understand.

Comment: try this:
1. set viewC's top anchor equal to Container View's top anchor with offset 120
2. set viewC's right anchor equal to Container View's right anchor with offset -10
3. set viewA's center Y equal to viewC's centerY.
4. set viewA's right anchor equal to viewC's left anchor with the offset x (x is whatever u want)

Comment: the big square is the screen

Comment: no matter what is the big square.

screen is just a big view.

Comment: can you help me with code i am begginner with constraints