# Wrong with Ssl pinner with swift

Tags: swift, ssl

i am following with this tutorial, https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/266

i showed the certificates with this code:

```
print(ServerTrustPolicy.certificates())
```

this showed me `[<cert(0x7f9d6551aa10) s: *.infinum.co i: SSL.com DV CA>]`

in this function:

```
@IBAction func testWithAlamofireDefaultPin() {
        print(ServerTrustPolicy.certificates())

        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = ["https://infinum.co": .pinPublicKeys(
                publicKeys: ServerTrustPolicy.publicKeys(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            )
        ]
    }
```

and then i get this wrong

```
Task <FF5BA60A-CAF1-4F4B-AA1C-F2C15DE52464>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

How i resolve this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, we recently changed our domain to a .com domain, so our DevOps did a bit of magic to keep everything in place.

I updated the example to use stackoverflow.com and everything should work now just fine.

Generally, if you're trying to test out these examples, I suggest using the end domain you're pinning against, it's a good way to find potential issues before going to production.

Comment: thank so much my dude, a question what is the end domain?

Comment: You  do SSL pinning in order to add an extra layer of security for API calls you're using. So, the domain for your API calls. Using the pin I provided as an example does nothing if you're developing an app for yourself.

Comment: No idea, I'll have a look once I get some free time again. It shouldn't matter, all of the methods displayed are alternatives, and you should need only one at most.

Comment: what version i should install ? git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git

Comment: I don't think I updated this for Alamofire 5. It shouldn't matter though, the changes should be superficial if you're implementing this in your own project.