# How save session in xamarin ios, i must use Xamarin.Auth?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How save session in xamarin ios, i must use Xamarin.Auth?

I also need to be able to check if a session already exists when the app starts that way I skip the login page if they are already signed in

```
public class SettingsManager : ISettingsManager
    {
        public string PersonalFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        // Write Information to a Local File
        public void WriteLocalFile(string FileName, string Data)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(PersonalFolderPath, FileName);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, Data);
        }

        }
```

i found this thread https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/117141/save-and-grab-session-id-and-other-data

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT i need your help!!!

Comment: You can save the session to a file as the thread described. And read it from file when you login, you can check the read result to know if it is the session you want. What's your problem?

Comment: i want a example worked, for help to a lot of people

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT but is not neccesary use xamarin.Auth?

Comment: Whether to use Xamarin.Auth is depending on you, you can choose which way to login your app. And there is already code example in that thread, go and try it. Which part you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save session data, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

To save a value for a given key in preferences:

```
Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");
```

To retrieve a value from preferences or a default if not set:

```
var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");
```